# Disable Xcode 8.0 Automatically Manage Signing by command line

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, fastlane

When enable `Automatically Manage Signing`, it will let `Jenkins` fail. Because that project needs to use different `Provisioning Profile` and `Signing Certificate` for code sign. The `fastlane` is configured and works well when disable that. Sometimes my partner will enable that for developing on his MacOS. And I don't know he checked that `Automatically Manage Signing`, then Jenkins complaint errors.

So, I hope I can disable it by script, then integrate it in the Jenkins CI system.

[image: Disable Automatically manage signing]

Answer (score 2):

you can use the plugin here 
https://github.com/hjanuschka/fastlane-plugin-update_project_codesigning

it gives you a fastlane action to toggle auto codesigning

Comment: I will try it. Thank you very much. ^___^

Comment: @Helmut Januschka, I love you so much ! ♥♥♥